# Why is width not included in style tag in css

Tags: html, css, email

if you look at the included picture i'm working with codeschool to learn HTML emails what i cant understand is why the width element is not included in the style tag and with it just says "600" and not "600px".

can anybody explain, thx in advance.

[image: here is the picture]

Answer (score 2):

Because It **accepts Pixels in width attribute.**

Please Check Following URL

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp

Answer (score 2):

W3Schools says that it uses pixels only, however in the past, percents and pixels used to be allowed. As of HTML 5 only pixel values are allowed there so there is no point to adding 'px'

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-width

Answer (score 1):

> In HTML 4.01 , width attribute accepts two units:

**1) Percent : use of `%` for it.**

```html
<img  width="20%" src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg">
```

**2)Pixel :** this is default and you should not use the unit.

```html
<img  width="50" src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg">
```

> In HTML5 , width attribute accepts just `pixel` without unit:

But

> in `inline` or `internal` and `external` styles, you can use of units.

```html
<img style="width: 50px"  src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg" >
```

Answer (score 1):

The "600" should, if used correctly, be the intrinsic width of the image. That is the number of pixels wide that the PNG image contains, and is there to help consumers of the HTML handle aspects of the image before it has downloaded it. For example, a user-agent might decide only to download it when it needs to display it, or not at all if it's likely to use too much expensive bandwidth.

This is different from how large it should be displayed on screen. That information should be supplied in the CSS.